# INSERT INTO with UNION Alias ERROR

Tags: ms-access, union, alias

This question is derived from the following post [UNION query not working](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/451859-union-query-not-working)

Fails:

```
INSERT INTO AssetControl  
SELECT *  
FROM CSVImport  
UNION SELECT *  
FROM AssetTemp;
```

Works:

```
INSERT INTO AssetControl  
SELECT U.* FROM  
(SELECT * FROM CSVImport  
UNION  
SELECT * FROM AssetTemp) AS U
```

I don't understand why an alias `U` needs to be created in order for the records to be successfully input into the `AssetControl` table. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Could you paste the actual error you were getting? It tends to help other people find the question.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: *Access is weird ;)*

Long answer is that Access has certain restrictions in the SQL syntax it supports. It requires parentheses around some constructions, for example when more than 2 tables are joined.

I think the same applies here. It's not that an alias is required, it's that (Access) syntax requires parentheses in `INSERT INTO tableA SelectQueryB;` when `SelectQuery` is a `UNION` query, even though the SQL standard does not require them. **I think<sup>[1]</sup>** that this works, too (and doesn't need an alias):

```
INSERT INTO AssetControl  
(SELECT * FROM CSVImport  
UNION  
SELECT * FROM AssetTemp) ;
```

<sup>[1]:</sup>  <sub>It appears that this is not allowed either.</sub>

---

Your solution works because it's equivalent to the standard use of `INSERT .. SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO AssetControl  
SELECT U.* 
FROM SomeTable AS U ;
```

where `SomeTable` is replaced by a derived table:

```
(SELECT * FROM CSVImport  
UNION  
SELECT * FROM AssetTemp)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - However, I have tried to encapsulate the entire 'SelectQueryB' into parentheses and this raises syntax errors. When I remove the parentheses, the query has no issues. Are you sure this is the root cause?  Access Version 2007-2013

Comment: TIL I learned that @ypercube has Access syntax memorized. That explains something.....

Comment: @JamesPeterMcConnell As I said *"**I think** that this works, too"* So, I was wrong! I don't have Access avaiable at this moment. When I do, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @JamesPeterMcConnell does this work? `INSERT INTO AssetControl  
(SELECT * FROM CSVImport  
UNION  
SELECT * FROM AssetTemp) AS U;`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I tried INSERT INTO AssetControl (SELECT * FROM CSVImport UNION SELECT * FROM AssetTemp) AS U;  - Unfortunately, this is providing a syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old but anybody who still seeks an answer - this should work:

```
INSERT INTO AssetControl  
SELECT * FROM  
(SELECT * FROM CSVImport  
UNION  
SELECT * FROM AssetTemp)
```

In case it still doesn't, try to name the columns explicitly in the outer `SELECT` clause e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO AssetControl  
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM  
(SELECT * FROM CSVImport  
UNION  
SELECT * FROM AssetTemp)
```